# Find duplicates in many columns query builder

Tags: database, querystring, laravel-framework

I have this code to find duplicates, but i compare All columns in same row, also it returns only one row

```
$groupBy = explode(',',$request['fields']);
   $duplicates = DB::table($module)
    ->select('*') 
    ->groupBy($groupBy)
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
    ->get();
```

What I need is to find the duplicates with (OR) not (And)
I want to find if there's a duplicate in Name or in Phone.

I also wanted to return All of the founded recorded to determine which one should I delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
$duplicates = DB::table($module)
      ->select('Name','Phone', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count')
      ->groupBy('Name', 'Phone')
      ->having('count', '>', 1)
      ->get();
```

Comment: it's not working probably, only return true if both phone and name are duplicated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097875/returning-full-duplicate-rows-using-laravels-query-builder#33098979 try the code in this link.

Comment: thanks, but i only returns the column, what about the find duplicates by OR